# How to write if condition in Angular Controller

Tags: angularjs, if-statement

There are two kind of buttons, let's say group one and group two. in group one  there are 2 buttons and in group two there are 3 buttons. Each of these buttons are supposed to send a unique id. Now the question is how to retrieve the buttons' id and also how to specify the following condition?
for example, if button1 from first group is active and if button2 from second group is active, then do something and so on.
The condition would be applied based on actions between these two groups.

Here's an example:

```
    <!-- group one -->
<div ng-controller = "btnCtrl as bc">
<ul class="nav nav-pills" role="tablist" ng-init="selectedTab = 'btn1';">
    <li class="nav-item">
         <a class="nav-link btn" role="button" ng-class="{'active':selectedTab === 'btn1'}" ng-click="selectedTab = 'btn1';">btn1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
         <a class="nav-link btn" role="button" ng-click="selectedTab = 'btn2';" ng-class="{'active':selectedTab === 'btn2'}">btn2</a>
    </li>
</ul>
    <!-- group two -->
    <div ng-cloak>
        <div class="row">
             <div class="col-sm-6" ng-repeat="btn in bc.btn" ng-click="bc.select('id',$index);" ng-class="{active: $index == bc.selected}">
             <p role="button"><span ng-bind="btn.name"></span></p>
             </div>
        </div>
    </div>

and here's the controller:
bc.btn = [
                  {
                      'id': 1,
                      'name': 'item1',
                  },
                  {
                      'id': 2,
                      'name': 'item2',
                  },
                  {
                      'id': 3,
                      'name': 'item3',
                  }
        ];
bc.selected = 0;
bc.select = function (id,index) {
    bc.selected = index;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? Do you have any code?

Comment: Please provide all relevant code as per [mcve]. We can't help you without some code context

Comment: Sorry for that, I've added a simple example... thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem,

The result could be achieved by using localStorage or sessionStorage, based on the application's need. So by having a function assigned to each button in group one and storing the id of each button in group two, then based on the condition the specific id can be retrieved.